# Images in IFRAME no longer showing after I log out of Flickr?

Tags: iframe, redirect, flickr

I have a iframe window which displays user's flickr images. I use the flickr.photos.search api to download the user's image from flickr. This works great when the user is logged into flickr.

But when I explicitly log off the user from flickr and the yahoo network and then attempt to download the flickr images, I get redirected to www.yahoo.com in a full browser window (not in my iframe).

If I remember correctly, I did not have this issue when I was not using iframes and I was being redirected to the yahoo login screen.

Any suggestions?

To elaborate, this URI - http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.howto.web.html, lists the below step -

4. Create an auth handler

When users follow your login url, they are directed to a page on flickr.com which asks them if they want to authorize your application. This page displays your application title and description along with the logo, if you uploaded one.

When the user accepts the request, they are sent back to the Callback URL you defined in step 2. The URL will have a frob parameter added to it. For example, if your Callback URL was http://test.com/auth.php then the user might be redirected to http://test.com/auth.php?frob=185-837403740 (The frob value in this example is '185-837403740').

This does not happen when I am in my iframe window but it does happen in my full browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the above question in the flickr forums and I received a response which said this cannot be done in iframes. So, I would need to rejig my UI to achieve this.